# How can I show that f is a diffeomorphism?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, manifolds

Let $G=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R^3}\mid x^2+y^2-z^2+1=0; z>0\} $ and $D=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x^2+y^2 <1\}$.

Let $f\colon G \rightarrow D $ be a mapping such that $$f(x,y,z)=\left( \frac x z, \frac y z \right)$$

How can I show that this is a diffeomorphism? (Which should be a bijection, where $f$ is differentiable and $f^{-1}$ is differentiable)

Comment: it is connected i misread sry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's check that $f$ takes its values in $D$. Indeed, from the definition of $G$, one gets :
$$\frac{x^2}{z^2}+\frac{y^2}{z^2}=1-\frac{1}{z^2}$$
Since $z=\sqrt{1+x^2+y^2}$, $0 \leq \frac{1}{z^2} <1$.

Now let's prove it is injective. Indeed, if $f(x_1,y_1,z_1)=f(x_2,y_2,z_2)$ then we must have $z_1=z_2$ (since $|f(x_1,y_1,z_1)|=|f(x_2,y_2,z_2)|$ and $z_i>0$) and therefore $x_1=y_1$ and $x_2=y_2$.

Now to see that it is surjective : let $(u,v)$ be in $D$ : then $u^2+v^2<1$. Let $z$ be a number such that $u^2+v^2 = 1-\frac{1}{z^2}$. Let $x = uz^2$, $y=vz^2$. Check that $f(x,y,z)=(u,v)$.

I'll leave the differentiability to you, it shouldn't be a problem.